# Flatlist's children saying "Function components cannot be given refs."

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I'm getting an error `"Warning: Function components cannot be given refs. Attempts to access this ref will fail"` when I attempt to add refs to the children of a Flatlist. However, it only seems to happen when I add the refs to the `UserinfoGridComponent` and not the `View` component.

Basically, what I believe is happening, from a bunch of googling, is that the flatlist's children are considered functional components, just as the error says, and as such cant accept refs. (but I'm confused because the child has setState...)

What I really need is just a ref inside the child (`UserinfoGridComponent`) so that I can scroll the flatlist as needed, from within the `UserinfoGridComponent` component. Is there a way to get this to work?

Parent:

```
class HomeScreen extends React.Component {
  displayType = ({ item, index }) => {

    const isBookmarked = (this.state.bookmarks.map(bookmark => bookmark.id).indexOf(item.id) !== -1)

    return (
      <View 
        ref={test => console.log("test ref 2", test)} 
        key={item.id} 
        style={[styles.shadowContainer, style={marginHorizontal: 15, marginBottom:25}]}>
        <UserinfoGridComponent
          ref={test => console.log("test ref 1", test)}
          checked={ isBookmarked }
          images={item.promoImages}
          firstImg={item.promoImages ? (item.promoImages[0] || null) : null}
          secondImg={item.promoImages ? (item.promoImages[1] || null) : null}
          avatar={item.avatar || ''}
          name={item.name || ''}
          mainSkill={User.extractSkill(item.skill)}
          secondarySkill={( item.otherSkills && item.otherSkills.length > 0 ) ? User.extractSkill(item.otherSkills[0]) : ''}
          city={item.location.locality}
          state={item.location.region}
          // key={index}
          index={index}
          user={item}
          onUserInfoPress={() => {
            this.props.navigation.navigate('Profile', { 
              user: item,
              clearAllFilters: this.clearAllFilters });
          }}
          onBookmarkPress={this.onBookmarkPress}
        />
      </View>
    )
  }


render() {

    const { creatorSearch } = this.props.data

    return (
      <View style={{flex:1, backgroundColor: 'white'}}>
        <Animated.View style={{ opacity: this.state.initialOpacityAnimation, flex: 1}}>
          <FlatList
            ref={(list) => { this.listRef = list }}
            contentInset={{top: 0, left: 0, bottom: 150, right: 0}}
            scrollIndicatorInsets={{top: 60, left: 0, bottom: 70, right: 0}}
            data={creatorSearch && this.state.initialContentLoaded ? creatorSearch.items : []}
            onEndReachedThreshold={0.3}
            onEndReached={() => this.scrollEnd()}
            ListHeaderComponent={this.listHeaderText}
            ListEmptyComponent={this.emptyListView}
            extraData={this.state.bookmarks.length}
            renderItem={this.displayType}
            scrollEventThrottle={1}
          />
        </Animated.View>
      </View>
    )
  }
}
```

Child:

```
class UserInfoGridComponent extends React.Component {

constructor(props) {
    super(props)


    this.state = { 
      loadedUser: { media: { items: [] }},
      promoImages: this.props.user.promoImages
    }
  }

render() {

    const combinedImages = this.state.loadedUser.media.items.length > 0 ? this.state.loadedUser.media.items : this.state.promoImages

    return (
      <View>
       <FlatList
        ref={ref => console.log("THIS IS A TEST", test)}
        horizontal={true}
        data={combinedImages}
        renderItem={this.imageDisplay}
        style={{padding:imageMargin*2}}
        showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false}
       />
      </View>
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

reference should be assigned as `ref={(ref) => this._flatlist = ref}`

and you can access flatlist by using `this._flatlist`

Comment: I've added this to the child Flatlist : `keyExtractor = {(item, index) => index.toString()}` But I'm still seeing the error `Warning: Function components cannot be given refs. Attempts to access this ref will fail. Check the render method of ("Child Component's Name").`